# <li> member moves when mouse hovering on another <li> member

Tags: html, css, navbar, navigationbar

Why does my `<li>` element move when I hover over another `<li>` member? When I try to make it static by setting position to absolute, its still won't locate statically...

Here's the code :

```css
/*Global Settings*/

a {
  color: white;
}
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
/********************/

/*Navigation Bar Setting*/

#navbar {
  background: red;
  height: 37px;
}
#navbar > ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
#navbar > ul > li {
  /*display: inline;*/
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar > ul > li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
#firsttab:hover > ul {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  top: 37px;
  left: 111px;
  background: rgb(119, 14, 14);
  position: absolute;
}
#secondtab:hover > ul {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  top: 37px;
  left: 261px;
  background: rgb(119, 14, 14);
  position: absolute;
}
#firsttab:hover > ul > li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 8px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
#secondtab:hover > ul > li {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  height: 8px;
}
#secondtab:hover > ul > li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
#firsttab:hover > ul > li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
#home {
  background: rgb(119, 14, 14);
  height: 16px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(119, 14, 14);
}
li > ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li > ul > li {
  display: none;
}
/********************/

#middle > ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li id="home">
      <a>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>News</a>
    </li>
    <li id="firsttab">
      <a>Computer</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Software</li>
        <li>Hardware</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Internet</a>
    </li>
    <li id="secondtab">
      <a>HandPhone</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Software</li>
        <li>Hardware</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Online Stream</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="middle">
  <ul>
    <li>tab</li>
    <li>konten</li>
    <li>tab</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**First screenshot**

[image: First screenshot]

**Second screenshot**

[image: Second screenshot]

Comment: That is some painfully specific CSS. Is there anyway you can clean it up to reduce the use of ID's and child selectors? You could just put a class .navbar on the nav and do .navbar li:hover {border-bottom: 5px transparent... } and reduce a lot of the repetition in this css.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;`  to your li like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
   /*Global Settings*/
   a{
   color: white;
   }
   body{
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   }
   /********************/
   /*Navigation Bar Setting*/
   #navbar{
   background: red;
   height: 37px;
   }
   #navbar > ul{
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   list-style: none;
   }
   #navbar > ul > li{
   /*display: inline;*/
   float: left;
   padding: 8px;
   height: 16px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   }
   #navbar > ul > li:hover{
   border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
   }
   #firsttab:hover > ul{
   margin: 0px;
   height: 60px;
   padding: 5px;
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right: 0px;
   top: 37px;
   left: 111px;
   background: rgb(119, 14, 14);
   position: absolute;
   }
   #secondtab:hover > ul{
   margin: 0px;
   height: 60px;
   padding: 5px;
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px;
   top: 37px;
   left: 261px;
   background: rgb(119, 14, 14);
   position: absolute;
   }
   #firsttab:hover > ul > li{
   display: block;
   padding: 10px;
   height: 8px;
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
            border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; 
   }
   #secondtab:hover > ul > li{
   display: block;
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
   height: 8px;
            border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; 
   }
   #secondtab:hover > ul > li:hover{
   border-bottom: 5px solid black; 
   }
   #firsttab:hover > ul > li:hover{
   border-bottom: 5px solid black; 
   }
   #home{
   background: rgb(119, 14, 14);
   height: 16px;
   border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(119, 14, 14);
   }
   li > ul{
   list-style: none;
   }
   li > ul > li{
   display: none;
   }
   /********************/
   #middle > ul{
   list-style: none;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li id="home"><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>News</a></li>
    <li id="firsttab"><a>Computer</a>
     <ul>
      <li>Software</li>
      <li>Hardware</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Internet</a>
    </li>
    <li id="secondtab"><a>HandPhone</a>
     <ul>
      <li>Software</li>
      <li>Hardware</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Online Stream</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
   <ul>
    <li>tab</li>
    <li>konten</li>
    <li>tab</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Updated my answer:

CSS:

```
    #firsttab:hover > ul > li{
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 8px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;    / *newly added */
            }
            #secondtab:hover > ul > li{
            display: block;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            height: 8px;
            border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;    / *newly added */
            }
```

Comment: Yea thanks, i know what you mean... We dont have to use border anymore right?

Comment: If you need border on hover you need to specify for li too else no need :)